# d3 force directed graph nodes stay at fixed position after filter

Tags: d3.js

In my d3 force directed scatter plot i try to make points disappear and re-appear by clicking on a legend key. After clicking the legend key, i would like the remaining points to regroup and not to stay fixed in the same position, leaving blank spaces (screenshots). When clicking again on the legend, they should fly in again.

I tried to remove the fill of the circles upon clicking on a legend key, which is working, but obviouly does not make the force do its work..

My code on blockbuilder.org: http://blockbuilder.org/dwoltjer/04a84646720e1f82c16536d5ef9848e8
[image: before][image: blank spaces remain after clicking purple legend key]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat the filtered data as new data and apply the `update`, `enter` and `exit` pattern:

```
   var node = svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data);

   node.exit().remove();


   node.enter().append("circle") 
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", radius)
   ......
```

The click event for `legend`:

```
  legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width - 18)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", color)
        .on("click", function (d) {

                        visible[d] = !visible[d];
                        var newdata = data.filter(function(e) { return visible[e.bank];});

                        DrawNode(newdata);

        });
```

Here is the update [blocks](http://bl.ocks.org/mpbastos/0642c93db437151b4a8e8467a1bca18d)

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thank you very much, exactly what i needed!! There is one thing now with animation: when clicking on teh "swap the x-axis variable" button a couple of times, the animation freezes and only restarts after clicking a legend key. Any ideas?

Comment: @WoltjerD: The `d3.force` is defined inside `DrawNode` function. The function that swap the axis was calling `force.resume` but `force` is undefined outside `DrawNode`. I have updated the blocks to call `DrawNode` everywhere it was calling `force.resume`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply deleting the nodes should be enough to make the force rearrange itself and group the nodes again. But, you will want to save the nodes to bring them back (possibly using a temporary array).

However, if you want the nodes to fly off screen (and back on), then what I'd do (using V4) is move the nodes to a new forcePoint that's way off screen:

```
 legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color)
    .on("click", function (d) {
      node.filter(function () {
           return this.dataset.bank === d;
           })
            position
           .force('x', d3.forceX(width/2).strength(20))
           .force('y', d3.forceY(height*2).strength(20));//should be twice the height of the svg, so way off the y axis. Or whichever direction you choose.
     });
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, clever idea to to use a point way off the screen! I may use that. I think I'll first stick to Marcelo's solution.